# How can I print a list of Firestore documents to console?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a user database that looks like this:

[image: Stole this picture from another place]

I would like to return an array or a map or a list or something that I can iterate through that maybe looks like this:

[Jack Danniels, Jonathan Wells, Fredrick Reich]

I have this following code:

```
void getData() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').getDocuments();
    var list = querySnapshot.documents;
    print(list);
  }
```

Printing "list" doesn't return what I want. This seems like it should be simple but I spent quite some time looking around. My end goal is to iterate through the list and identify duplicate names at any one point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you're showing is working with Firestore, but the screenshot is showing Realtime Database.  These are two different database products.  You can't write code using the Firestore SDK to read data in Realtime Database.  If you want to work with content in Firestore, you'll need to actually populate collections and documents into a Firestore database.

Comment: Wow, I'm silly. You're right; I will update it and resubmit the question, though I think the overall set up would be around the same